# Why wpf ResourceManager GetString (localization) returns english only

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, resources

I have a localization issue.

Here,in below code (auto generated in designer file) the str always returns english values even if the application is in other locale.

```
.
ResourceManager rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("A.b.Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
.
.
var culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture; //zh-CN selected as locale
var str = rm.GetString(key, culture); //always returns english  :(
.
```

My resource file sits under the zh-CN folder wherever the executables got built:

"..\zh-CN\A.b.**resources**.dll" (checked the dll internally, it has the all the strings-values available in cn language)

Project name is: A.b

Namespace in the designer file is: A.b.Properties

I am not able to figure out why the application returns only the english values and not the locale specific ones!
I tried it a lot but unable to figure out whats wrong!

Though i, noticed that the _resourceSets [zh-CN] object Values has all english items in it.
[image]

Any idea/reference is much much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At application startup, my application determines my preferred language culture, gets the system `CultureInfo` object for it, and sets the following two values.  Are you doing something like this?

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = desiredCulture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture              = desiredCulture;
```

Also, I don't know if it matters but all of my language-specific resource DLLs live in subfolders that are just the `TwoLetterISOLanguageName` code from the `CultureInfo` in question.

So for example, my French translations live in the "fr" subfolder.  Are you sure your resources should not live in a "\zh" subfolder, instead of "\zh-cn"?

Comment: Thanks.  Yes already doing that here. Actually my whole application translates fine, just not for the controls under this project. I have other projects within same visual studio solution, they work fine. I saw that the 'culture' object correctly points to {zh-CN}. Or instead if i do.. rm.GetString(key, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("zh-CN"))  .. still the same issue. For the folder name , it should be under zh-CN.

Comment: Tried with two letter folder name "\zh" , still same issue.

Comment: Wait so you are saying that if you `GetString() `from *another project* it properly retrieves the Chinese strings but not from this one?

Comment: Also, after you do the above setting of culture values, are you subsequently calling `FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)));`?  That's the sort of thing I was always told to do in my WPF so I do.

Comment: My other (main) entry project (in the same solution) has its own separate .dll file under that zh-CN folder. That one is able to show correct strings.

Comment: If i have to use this above line of code don't i have to add it inside all of my ui components in this A.b project !? (That will be a big change in my case)

Comment: In my case, I only do the `OverrideMetadata` thing one time, in my app at startup.  But it does happen *after* the setting the thread/default culture values that I talked about before.  Both steps are taken just once by my application.  Afterwards, all loaded assemblies/modules properly show the strings from the selected language.  (Having two people named "Joe" here is confusing!)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Lets see where i can utilize this code. In my existing (entry) application its not used anywhere. I'll report back.. Thanks Joe, (senior! :)

Comment: For now, I ended up moving all the resources from lower projects into the main entry project's resource file. Cheers.